# what does "outb" in AT&T asm mean?

Tags: assembly, x86, att, ioports, hardware-port

I am reading some code of Linux.
The keyboard.S has something like

```
outb %al,$0x61
```

and

```
inb $0x61,%al
```

I think the pending 'b' means 'byte', but i still cannot find what these instructions mean.

Comment: Intel cores have an I/O bus, distinct from the memory bus.  Port 0x61 is a keyboard control register.  http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=258828

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are IN & OUT instructions in x86 used for?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3215878/what-are-in-out-instructions-in-x86-used-for)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[`OUT`](http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2011/readings/i386/OUT.htm) and [`IN`](http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2011/readings/i386/IN.htm) are instructions for transferring data between I/O ports. Those are a couple of links I found which provide a bit more information.

As you mentioned, the `b` is the `byte` form of those instructions, which is appropriate since you're using the lower byte of `ax` (`al`).

Answer (score 5):

Yes, the out port and in port instructions can be encoded for 8 bits of data or 16 bits of data.  The b indicates byte which is the 8 bit version.