# how to read/write USB device

Tags: x86, operating-system, usb

Recently I'm learning the operating system, I know how to read and write floppy disks, disks, VGA interface through IO ports, now I want to know how to control USB devices, because I didn't find the IO port number related to USB

Comment: IBM-PCs didn't have USB since it hadn't been invented yet.  It's new enough to use a modern MMIO interface, not slow IO ports.  https://wiki.osdev.org/Universal_Serial_Bus .  If you aren't already searching the osdev wiki before asking SO questions, start doing that.  (e.g. google for `osdev usb`)

Comment: Related: [The lowest level function to handle a user input](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58569102) / [Best practise for reading from a USB stick in real mode](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/121237667) / [Who Decides Between I/O Mapped and Memory Mapped I/O (x86)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56819190)