# What is the purpose of two address spaces in x86?

Tags: io, x86, cpu-architecture, address-space

As I know, nowdays, x86's IO address space is used almost only for legacy devices. E.g ARM and RISC-V have only one address space, so, what is the idea behind multiple address spaces?

Comment: I'd say to have all the memory space dedicated to -  that is, memory. For the ancient 16 bit wide address bus (we are talking legacy here, think 8085) it could only address 64KB of memory, which is not that big.

Comment: So, second address space makes sense only in systems with relatively small memory address space?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3215878/what-are-in-out-instructions-in-x86-used-for has some answers that discuss the rationale and history.